# Pinescript | Partition array by density/proximity

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm working on a strategy and my current goal is to draw support and resistance channels.
For now, I can draw multiple S&R using pivot points and add them on the chart (only pivot high here).

[image: graph with pivot points]

As you can see, it's pretty clear that there are **4 different levels in this situation**.
Here's the array containing all the PHs: `[1.09118, 1.09192, 1.10201, 1.076, 1.07898, 1.07614, 1.06937, 1.06714, 1.06866, 1.07396, 1.07396, 1.07448, 1.07814, 1.09038]`

**QUESTION:**
Is there an easy way to partition this array (or any given array) in such a way that I get in output *n* array of numbers corresponding to the different clusters ?
I've looked into Jenks Natural Breaks but it's maybe too much for what I want to achieve.

**EXAMPLE**:
Let's take an array of pivot highs: `[1,2,3,5,10,11,13,65,70]`
I would like to partition the array so it output something like this: `[[1,2,3,5],[10,11,13],[65,70]]`

**FULL CODE:**

```
//@version=5
strategy("Support and Resistance", overlay=true)

// ============================================================================================================ //
// =============================================TIME RANGE===================================================== //
// ============================================================================================================ //

// CHOOSE DATES
i_dateFilter    = input(true,  "═════ Date Range Filtering ═════")
i_fromYear      = input.int(2023,   "From Year",    minval = 1900)
i_fromMonth     = input.int(1,      "From Month",   minval = 1, maxval = 12)
i_fromDay       = input.int(22,     "From Day",     minval = 1, maxval = 31)
i_toYear        = input.int(2023,   "To Year",      minval = 1900)
i_toMonth       = input.int(3,      "To Month",     minval = 1, maxval = 12)
i_toDay         = input.int(23,      "To Day",       minval = 1, maxval = 31)

// CREATE CONDITION
start     = timestamp(i_fromYear, i_fromMonth, i_fromDay, 00, 00)
finish    = timestamp(i_toYear, i_toMonth, i_toDay, 23, 59)
window()  => (time >= start and time <= finish) or not i_dateFilter ? true : false

// DISPLAY COLORED BACKGROUND
showDate = input(defval = true, title = "Show Date Range") 
bgcolor(color = showDate and window() ? color.new(color.gray, 90) : na)

// ============================================================================================================ //
// ================================================CODE======================================================== //
// ============================================================================================================ //

leftBars = input(5)
rightBars = input(5)
ph = ta.pivothigh(close, leftBars, rightBars)
plot(ph, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, color= color.blue, offset=-rightBars)

var float[] allPh = array.new_float(0)

if ph and window()
    line.new(bar_index - rightBars, ph, last_bar_index, ph, color = color.blue)
    array.push(allPh, ph)
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what are the '4 different levels in this situation' ? Also, your question : "Is there an easy way to partition this array (or any given array) in such a way that I get in output n array of numbers corresponding to the different clusters ?" is not so clear... what is a partition of an array  ? Can you give us an example ?

Comment: Code has been updated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try dividing the array by the % change of the array element. I would first create 10 arrays (array-1, array-2, ...) and divide the main array in the loop. Create arrays with a reserve and use only a part